# User redirecting in struts2 with data not working

Tags: struts2

I am new to struts2. I am working on the struts2 with spring application. 
I developed user registration functionality. In this registration process have the 3 steps(3forms). First page is step1 contains some fields, second page is step2 contain some other fields and step3 contains some other fields.I used session map in the action class to put the all field values of all forms.After submission form in step3 it goes to call rest service and give the response.If the response is OK then i am redirecting to success page step4. In some cases if user is already exits then it gives response existed user then am redirecting to step5 page. In this page i used one message " Sorry the user is already exists" and with one link "Home Page".

I used this link `<s:a id="next" href="/sample/register/user.action"> Homepage </s:a>` in step5 page. After clicking on this link it goes to homepage(means step1 page) fine,but it doesn't contain user entered values. I have to maintain all field values in the step1,step2,step3 process. How to achieve this problem.

Please any one can give suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using session map to persist values being entered by the user, i believe they should be available in the session until you have not removed them from the session or session expired.more over when you do redirect a new request -response cycle started by the framework and a new value stack will be created that means all old values will be lost.

From your description i believe you are creating a wizard like functionality and if this is the case i believe struts2 provide a more elegant and flexible solution

1. [ScopeInterceptor](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ScopeInterceptor.html)

This is designed to solve a few simple issues related to wizard-like functionality in Struts

Still you need to show how you trying to show the values in the form being filled by the user if something fails or when user is already exists in the system as described in your case.In this case you need to fetch object/data from the session.

Comment: Hi Umesh, Thanks for response.The 3 pages in the registration process are different pages.After submitting the step1 page it goes to action class and put the UserBean in Map<String, Object> session. Any errors are there in that page1 it redirects to same input page and it shows the user entered data.same process is avialable in step2 and in step3 page have rest service call.After this call if response  is "existed user" then i have to redirect the user to first step of registration process with all data of user entered values. Please give me suggestion.

Comment: when it goes back to the main pag eon user exists, how many objects are there in session? will it be for all three steps or only for last one

Comment: I dint used any HttpSession object in action class.I used RegisterUserAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware, ServletResponseAware, SessionAware classes. I am adding the UserBean information to session.put("personBean", getPersonInfo());

Comment: `SessionAware` is a convient way to inject HTTPSession as a map in your Action class

Comment: And i used the following variables in my action class.            private UserInfo userInfo;
private Map<String, Object> session;                                I am adding UserBean information to session.put("userBean", getUserInfo()); In step2,getting this userBean from session and adding the additional information to userbean and again put to session.After rest service call done,i printed form values in action class they are avilable from session. How to get this UserBean in step1 jsp page and show the values in the form if the user is exitsted user.

Comment: need to use like `%{#session.myUserObject}` in your JSP where session is your session object and `myUserObject` is the object you storing in the session you can den access properties of your `myUserObject`

Comment: @user1471305:IF it solve your problem you can mark the answer as accepted so that some one with same problem can get solution instaantly